# Determine the pod/instance API endpoint of a Salesforce org?

Tags: apex, api, sandbox, force.com-sites, mydomain

Say I want to retrieve my API endpoint from a Visualforce Page or a Force.com Site, I can try:

```
Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
```

But the return value is all over the place. It could be any of the following:

- `http://pod.salesforce.com` (from a batch apex class)
- `https://c.na1.visual.force.com` (a local Visualforce Page)
- `https://mysite.secure.force.com` (from a Force.com Site)
- `https://ns.pod.visual.force.com` (some page in a managed package)

This wreaks havoc on the Remote Site Settings, and gets worse with Sites and Communities.

## So how do I get just `"https://na1.salesforce.com"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use:    `Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()`

<sub>Thanks, [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67865/tim-lewis)</sub>

---

Note behaviour changes between releases and is sensitive to My Domain settings:

- @Future context returns `https://na1.salesforce.com`
- Visualforce context returns `https://na1.salesforce.com`
- Force.com Site context returns `https://na1.salesforce.com`
- @Future context returns `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com`
- Visualforce context returns `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com`
- Force.com Site context returns `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com`

[My Domain](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/domain_name_brand_your_org.htm) is mandatory in new orgs effective Winter '21. 
[Enhanced Domains](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/domain_name_enhanced.htm) is mandatory in all orgs effective Summer '22.

```
// Not to be confused with Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl()
// http://na1.salesforce.com (can happen in async apex)
// https://c.na1.visual.force.com (local Visualforce Page)
// https://ns.na1.visual.force.com (packaged Visualforce Page)
// https://custom.my.salesforce.com (org has My Domain enabled)
// https://sandbox-mydomain.na1.force.com (sandbox site with My Domain...)
```

**See also the [Salesforce Identity API](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm) which attests the pod/instance endpoint.**

Comment: Seems this method get the custom domain (https://devtest--XXXXXXX.cs1.my.salesforce.com) instead of the one only with instance on it (https://cs1.salesforce.com) if the org has enabled custom domain, though custom domain can still access SFDC REST API

Comment: @OscarTang yep :-) if custom domain enabled, everyone should use it

Comment: would this work in Lightning mode?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the pod of the org via SOQL, assuming the running user has access to the Organization table:

`SELECT InstanceName  FROM Organization`

Depending on your use case, this may be a better option than calling out to the Identity API (which can't be done from synchronous contexts such as a Post Install Handler, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can query any user's fullPhotoUrl

`SELECT fullPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE userType = 'Standard' LIMIT 1`

this field always contains at least the URL of an icon. The URL exposes the pod. E.g.
`https://c.eu2.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T`
or
`https://acmeinc--c.na39.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/F`

A regex like `/.*\.(.*)\.content/` gives you the pod.

Comment: Isn't this field only exposed when Chatter is enabled?