# How to get instance name/key via API

Tags: rest, instance

Is there a way to get the instance name of a Salesforce organisation (like `na41`) via the REST API in a reliable way? I've looked at existing resources available and they do not seem to expose that. I also considered parsing it out of the `instance_url` value, but it could vary if the org is using a custom domain.

Comment: Do these links help? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64616/how-to-get-salesforce-instance-url and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61091/determine-the-pod-instance-api-endpoint-of-a-salesforce-org and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getSalesforceBaseUrl?

Comment: @AndyHitchings That works fine when queried from within Salesforce, but not in an external application sadly.

Comment: I don't know if this will help or not, but in Workbench, you can go to Session Information > Connection > Endpoint and it will show you the endpoint which includes the instance. How to get the same via REST I cannot tell you. But that might at least help point you in the right direction.

Comment: @crmprogdev Sadly, I'm getting the custom domain from there as well =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little bit of reverse engineering, it seems like we can get the instance key using this REST endpoint:

`https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instanceAliases/[custom-domain]`

As an example, if your Salesforce instance URL is:

- https://ci.my.salesforce.com/

You can get the key at:

- https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instanceAliases/ci

---

In JavaScript:

```
fetch('https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instanceAliases/ci')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(function (body) {
        console.log(body.instanceKey);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err)
    });
```

Comment: This is not working for my sandbox Org, my custom domain is fscinsurance108--sandboxorg. The org url is https://fscinsurance108--sandboxorg.my.salesforce.com

Comment: This method does not work on Sandboxes.  It worked on my production box