# How to get instance name/key via API for sandbox Org

Tags: rest, instance

I have gone through all previous answers, I found this useful [How to get instance name/key via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155467/how-to-get-instance-name-key-via-api)

The rest API [https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instanceAliases/[custom-domain]](https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instanceAliases/%5Bcustom-domain%5D) works only for production Orgs and not sandbox custom domain.
Eg: My sandbox Org URL is fscinsurance108--sandboxorg.my.salesforce.com

But https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/instanceAliases/fscinsurance108--sandboxorg is not returning any data.

Any suggestion on how can I make it work?

I mainly want to get instance through JavaScript code, if there is any better way other than rest API, that would also work for me.
I have SID and OrgId populated in my code already.

Comment: If it doesn't work on this screen then likely there is no known exposed API for this. https://status.salesforce.com/. By SID you mean session Id?

Comment: Yes @manjit5190, SID is the session ID.